# Dispatch event to popupmanager without reference to instance

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, actionscript-3

I'm fairly experienced with Flex 4, but I still haven't needed frameworks yet (I like to do everything myself) and don't want to use them either, I know it's advantages and have learned how to use one of them, but still, no.

How can I dispatch an event in the main application and have a component inside a popupmanager to react to that event? All this dispatching the event within the main app and NOT aiming it to the popupmanager or the component instance, I want to be able to fire the event and not care about who gets it or if anyone reacts to it at all so if that is possible then I wouldn't care about keeping track of said popups.

I already dispatch an event from the component and receive it in the main application by bubbling the event and therefore being agnostic of each other, now I want it backwards.
Note: I have used singletons, but it's not the approach I need this time.

Comment: Actually I did: "I want to be able to fire the event and not care about who gets it or if anyone reacts to it at all so if that is possible then I wouldn't care about keeping track of said popups".
By this, I meant it in a general way, so I can do it from now on.

And just to clarify, I have tried using frameworks and so far it just added a lot of overwork and the size of the projects I have worked in didn't take advantage of any of the great features that those frameworks are meant to give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me you are in desperate need of RobotLegs, you seem to be asking how to to create/use an event bus system in order to de-couple your components which is exactly what robotlegs is amazing at.

One thing you should definitely also look at is ActionScript 3 Signals. Signals is an approach to make strongly typed events like .NET Framework, instead of the magic strings event system, and is a fantastic easy bolt on addition to any Flash/Flex project.

Another way that is common is a mediator/controller singleton pattern. Let's say this is an automotive application, and we have a service layer that behind the scenes is receiving some data from the server, whilst at the same time our popup is behind displayed. One way we solve this problem is create a singleton based controller for our data like PartsController. It also has some public const Signals like `SingalDataUpdated`. The popup can now do something like `PartsController.SignalDataUpdated.add(OnPartsUpdated)`. `OnPartsUpdated` is a local method inside the popup that can now react to the event as necessary and has no coupling to any other UI component. This is typically the approach we take and ensure that no UI component has explicit knowledge of any other UI component, and instead only talk to the controllers. One thing you need to ensure though is when the popup is closed remove the signal lister.

Again though, RobotLegs does most of all these for you and encourages some very great architecural best-pracitces. I would highly recommend you read through their documenation and get familiar with it. It will change your life when you realize how modular and maintainable it helps make your code.

Good luck!

**Update regarding context and singletons**
The idea regarding a context is to create a single singleton known as your application's context that stores the instances of what would be your other singletons. [Inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (IoC) and RobotLegs just wires things together so it dosen't look like absolute crap to work with, but you can just use a simple IoC injector like [Swiz](http://swizframework.jira.com/wiki/display/SWIZ/IoC+Container) or [SwiftSuspenders](https://github.com/tschneidereit/SwiftSuspenders) which RobotLegs is built upon. So, for example, you might hit a particular controller like:

```
AppContext.Instance.ProductController.SignalProductAdded.add(OnProductAdded);
```

But that is a bit ridiculous to try to access everything this way. Here comes RobotLegs to the rescue. Instead define injection rules in your RobotLegs context, so if a component asks for a UserController via an inject metadata tag, everything would get the same UserController. Exactly like a singleton, but correctly so in your component define;

```
[Inject] public var _objProductController:ProductController;
```

Now your component can work with the controller object as if it was its own, but instead it was injected in by RobotLegs on construction. For me and and most of my products I build a few base objects like `GroupBase`, `PanelBase`, `PopupPanelBase`, etc. that extend the proper component and already have all the controller injection properties so any component derived from these already connect to the proper controllers as needed.

For your simple project, it's like easier to roll your own and just create a single singleton for your context to hold your controllers and communicate with application's context that way.   These are all pretty high level architecural decisions and everyone works differently at this level based on their experience, preference, or whatever. The most important thing is that it works for you, and you are comfortable with the architecture. RobotLegs helps make everything very decoupled which has some amazing unforseen benefits later.

Good luck!

Comment: A Singleton is what I use, and what I wanted to avoid. Either way I will get deeper into robotlegs, I use signals all the time and it's integration with them is very nice, Thanks.

Comment: A singleton in of itself isn't horrible, they just need to be used sparingly and carefully, and ideally under the idea of a context, which essentially just contains a pointer to our singletons , which robot legs does a wonderful job of organizing and simplifying

Comment: Interesting, never saw it that way before, seems like I need to read a lot more about robotlegs and stop being afraid of frameworks making everything more complicated :/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question:

> how can I dispatch an event in the
>   main application and have a component
>   inside a popupmanager to react to that
>   event

Inside your pop up component, you can do something like this:

```
var app:Application = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as Application;
app.addEventListener('myCustomEvent',onMyCustomEvent);
```

Now any instances of the myCustomEvent that are dispatched by the main Application class will fire the handler in the popup.  Also, any instance of the myCustomEvent that bubble up to to the main Application class will fire the handler in the popup.

I'm not sure if this is a good idea.  Accessing the topLevelApplication will add external dependencies to your pop up which may reduce re-use of said component in the long term.  Accessing the topLevelApplication is not a decision I would take on without thought.

If you were trying to ask a different question; it is unclear to me from your post, which I found kind of confusing.

Comment: well, yeah, that's a way to do it, but only if I fire the popup from the main app, but not if the popup is being created inside a module.
In simpler words, I want to be able to fire an event and have it bubble up to the popup, without pointing the listener to anything outside the component, so the component can be created as a popup anywhere and anything can respond to it, not only the main app.

Comment: @Gustav Xyrer Try dispatching events from SystemManager instance

Comment: @Gustav Xyrer I'm pretty sure you can't have an event bubble up to a popUp because a popUp won't be in the display list heirachy as a parent to the component dispatching the event.  Aren't modules self contained apps?  What type of Flex Popup would not have a reference to some topLevelApplication?  If you need communication through Modules; I believe a LocalConnection is one way; but that will be very different approach, and use case, than event.  It sounds like you want to use bubbling for something it can't do.

Comment: It seems that is correct, it can't be done for that same reason, bubbling only goes to parents, not children. It would be an awesome feature though. Back to singletons then. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking further into what Flextras.com said (Jeffry Houser I presume), this feat is impossible, events never bubble to children, only to parents.
Therefore, this has to be done in a central event repository approach, which is the way frameworks do it mostly.

This is indeed one of the problems solved by dependencies injection found in some frameworks as robotlegs.

Comment: Actually, Flex events has [3 phases](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html).  Children *can* capture an event on the capturing phase.  The problem you're trying to solve is that a popup is not on the normal display list, but on a separate one.

Comment: @J_A_X "Children can capture an event on the capturing phase" -Well, I would think that is not the case, based on this: "Flex examines an event's ancestors in the display list" but I will conduct more tests just to be sure.